# Proof that energy of a free body is constant, using the derivate

Tags: derivatives, physics

Ok, what I'm trying to prove is the law of conservation of energy for a free fall. Let the downward direction be positive. We want to prove that:

$$mgh+\frac{mv^2}{2}=constant$$

For this, we try to prove that the derivate of the function is constant:

$$\frac{d}{dt}(mgh+\frac{mv^2}{2})=0 $$
$$mg\frac{dh}{dt}+Fv=0 $$

Applying Newton's law we get $$F=mg$$

Now, $\frac{dh}{dt}=v$

$$mgv+Fv=0 $$
$$Fv+Fv=0 $$

And it doesn't cancel out..

I understand the principle, and I have been able to prove it without using the derivate..but now it seems that I can't do it. I've been applying in a lot of problems. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that $v=-\frac{dh}{dt}$. It increases as you come down and decrease $h$

Comment: Ohh, right. thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Applying Newton's 2nd law and projecting on z, we get :
$$-m\frac{dv}{dt}=\parallel \vec{W}\parallel=mg $$
Then you multiply by v
$$-mv\frac{dv}{dt}=mgv\\
\frac{-d(\frac{mv²}{2})}{dt}=mg\frac{dh}{dt}\\ 
\frac{d(\frac{mv²}{2}+mgh)}{dt}=0\\
QED$$

Comment: What is the P vector?

Comment: P is the French notation, W the English one.

Comment: But why is the minus sign in fron of mg? the downward direction is positive, so we have: ma=mg

Comment: Hopefully, it's the same result no matter your choice for the axe :
if the downward direction is positive, then $-m\frac{dv}{dt}=\parallel \vec{W}\parallel$, otherwise $m\frac{dv}{dt}=-\parallel \vec{W}\parallel$